# Get plotly event xaxis object without firing an event

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

In [Plotlys documentation](https://plot.ly/javascript/hover-events/#capturing-hover-events-pixels) about hover events you can access an xaxis object attached to the event (see code below). This xaxis object is a completely different object from the xaxis layout you create yourself.

```
myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function(data){
    var xaxis = data.points[0].xaxis; // <-- This is what I'm after
});
```

This object has some nice functions to convert pixel coordinates to x-values and vice versa but I can't get hold of it until a hover event is fired. Is there any way of accessing it without having to fire an event?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know which xaxis attributes you are trying to access.

If it is just the axis range you are after, try `myPlot.layout.xaxis`.
Otherwise you might have to look into plotly's internal axis object which you can find under `myPlot._fullLayout.xaxis`.